# Как реализовать вектор стеков в C++?

Tags: c++

Следующая запись выдает ошибку:

```
vector < stack < int > > a(n, stack< int >);
```

> Ошибка    C2275   std::stack>>: недопустимое использование этого типа в качестве выражения

Comment: Либо `vector<stack<int>> a(n, stack<int>());`, либо просто `vector<stack<int>> a(n);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <stack>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::stack<int>> stack_list { 10 };
    return 0;
}
```

Конструктор:

```
explicit vector( size_type count, 
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Достаточно указать количество копий.